# Python script to filter last 12 months of data in each category

Tags: python, pandas, subset

I have date frame where i have to subset the  values based on the last 12 months data . Every category will not have equal number of rows ie the frequency is not same. So we have to sum the values with start date as the latest date present for that category and 12 months back . now in this number of values can differ like can have one single value to 12 values and so on ie it is not fixed

Below is the sample data :

```
RIC         DIVIDENDEXDATE       Adjusted 
==============================================
TECL.P      12/22/2020             0
TECL.P      9/22/2020              0
TECL.P      6/23/2020              0
TECL.P      3/24/2020              0.019
TECL.P      12/23/2019             0.111
TECL.P      9/24/2019              0.007
CSML.OQ     12/30/2020             0.146
CSML.OQ     9/24/2020              0.069
CSML.OQ     6/24/2020              0.62
CSML.OQ     3/25/2020              0.018
CSML.OQ     12/30/2019             0.0657
CSML.OQ     9/24/2019              0.6585
```

Here each group will be RIC and date has to be picked from DIVIDENDEXDATE. We should keep date which falls between the maximum/latest date for each RIC and whatever the rows coming within 12 months from the latest date .

I tried with the following code

```
df = data2.set_index('DividendExDate').last('12M')
```

but it is not working

Answer (score 1):

You should first turn your date column into a proper date format on which ordering can be understood:

```py
import pandas as pd
data2.DIVIDENDEXDATE = pd.to_datetime(data2.DIVIDENDEXDATE)
```

Then, filter rows in each group based on the distance between `DIVIDENDEXDATE` and the maximum date within the group:

```py
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
filtered_df = (data2.groupby('RIC')
                    .apply(lambda g: g[g['DIVIDENDEXDATE'] >= (g['DIVIDENDEXDATE'].max()-relativedelta(years=1))])
                    .reset_index(level=0, drop=True))
```

Am I answering your question?

Comment: Yes this is what i was expecting however there was parenthis missing in the end , rest is fine

Comment: Oops pasting error, fixing this. Please consider accepting the answer if it solved the problem 